# The equivalent of the standing order in the internet age for the UK specifically

Tags: united-kingdom, rent, electronic-payment, direct-debit

I have purchased a parking spot in a busy town which I want to rent out for a monthly fee.  I have found someone who wants to pay a rent and is happy to  have an arrangement indefinitely.  When I have done similar things in the past when I had a business renting out equipment, I would setup a standing order.  I would find out what bank they were with, get a standing order form from their bank, get them to fill in and then drop off to their bank.

But with the internet and electronic commerce is there some easier way to set this type of thing up? e.g. can I just get them to pay through some online banking arrangement?

Comment: What about PayPal?

Comment: It may be called a recurring payment or automatic payment in your bank's online banking system.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A standing order is still the right way to do this. Most bank accounts have online access and will let your customer setup the standing order online, without having to fill in a paper form.

Comment: For example, the [first direct app](http://www3.firstdirect.com/demos/ibdemo/regular_payments.shtml) allows you to set up standing orders in it, which is handy since first direct don't even *have* branches with paper forms in...